# Hide rows selectively in a WPF Data Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF Datagrid which for which the item source is a list.
Here is the code:

```
ReleaseDataGridView.ItemsSource = DisplayReleaseList;
```

where DisplayReleaseList is defined as:

```
List<ReleaseDataItem> DisplayReleaseList = new List<ReleaseDataItem>();
```

and ReleaseDataItem is a class with few fields and their repective properties.
I add a few ReleaseDataItem objects to DisplayReleaseList and then set it as ItemsSource for ReleaseDataGridView

I want to have a field/property in ReleaseDataItem class which decides whether to show this row in the grid or not.

For example:
If there aree two fields, say **bool visible** and **string name** in the class ReleaseDataItem and I write the code as:

```
ReleaseDataItem obj1 = new ReleaseDataItem(false,"abc"); //passed to constructor
ReleaseDataItem obj2 = new ReleaseDataItem(true,"xyz");
DisplayReleaseList.Add(obj1);
DisplayReleaseList.Add(obj2);
ReleaseDataGridView.ItemsSource = DisplayReleaseList;
```

Then grid would have only row that corresponds to obj2 (second object).
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use a CollectionViewSource with a filter. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You could also use the live-filtering/live-shaping feature of CollectionViewSource instead (available since WPF4.5). More infos here: http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/10/05/wpf-4-5-%E2%80%93-part-10-live-shaping/

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the source in a collection view gives You the ability to sort or filter:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ReleaseDataItem obj1 = new ReleaseDataItem(false, "abc"); //passed to constructor
        ReleaseDataItem obj2 = new ReleaseDataItem(true, "xyz");
        DisplayReleaseList.Add(obj1);
        DisplayReleaseList.Add(obj2);
        ListCollectionView itemsSource = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(DisplayReleaseList);
        itemsSource.Filter = x => ((ReleaseDataItem)x).Visible;
        ReleaseDataGridView.ItemsSource = itemsSource;
    }

    public List<ReleaseDataItem> DisplayReleaseList { get; private set; } = new List<ReleaseDataItem>();
}

public class ReleaseDataItem
{
    public ReleaseDataItem(bool visible, string value)
    {
        Visible = visible;
        Value = value;
    }

    public string Value { get; private set; }
    public bool Visible { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Checked with live filter, but doesn't work. CanChangeLiveFiltering is true, but when set the Visible to false, the view still shows the row.